# Text Will Not Fill Up Div

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I am designing a stat board for a call center and I am having trouble getting 2 elements to size up correctly.  I have used an automatic text resizer called FitText(link below).  I have gotten every other element to work with FitText except the 100% and 100 listed in the code.  I cannot figure out why the 100% and the 100 just stay so small compared to the sizes of the divs they are contained in.  Both containers are 100% width.  I have played around with hundreds of CSS combinations to no avail.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.  Via the requests below, here is the JSFiddle link.

http://jsfiddle.net/neggly/57tVW/

**CSS**

```
#wrap {
    position: absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color: black;
}

#statuscolorwrap
{
    background-color: aqua;
    float: left;
    width: 1%;
    height: 100%;
}

#numberwrap
{
    background-color: #ff0;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
}

#announcementwrap
{
    background-color: coral;
    float: left;
    width: 79%;
    height: 100%;
}

#queuewrapper
{
    height:40%;
    width:100%;
    float: top;
    background-color: darkorchid;
}

#queuecolors
{
    height:40%;
    width:100%;
    float: top;
    background-color: cadetblue;
}

#queuepercentage
{
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    float: top;
    background-color: chartreuse;
}

#queueholding
{
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    float: bottom;
    background-color: crimson;
}

#topcolor
{
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    float: top;
    background-color: darkseagreen;
}

#bottomcolor
{
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    float: bottom;
    background-color: moccasin;
}

#datetimewrapper
{
    width:100%;
    height:5%;
    float: top;
    background-color: deepskyblue;
}

#messages
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 60%;
    float: top;
    background-color: darkorchid;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.messagewrapper
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    float:top;
    background-color: azure;
}

.messageimportance
{
    float:left;
    width: 5%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: darkslategrey;
}

.messagesubject
{
    float:left;
    width: 95%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blanchedalmond;
}

h1
{
    font: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align: center;
}

h2
{
    font: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align: center;
}

h3
{
    font: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align: center;
}

#anpicturewrap
{
    float:top;
    width:100%;
    height:45%;
    background-color: darkcyan;
}

#antextwrap
{
    float:top;
    width:100%;
    height:50%;
    background-color: darkkhaki;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

img
{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
}

h4
{
    font: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
}

#text
{
    width: auto;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-right:40px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.subjecttext
{
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Virginia Summary</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="base.css"/>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/libs/jquery/jquery.fittext.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrap">
            <div id="numberwrap">
                <div id="queuewrapper">
                    <div id="queuepercentage">
                        <div class="subjecttext">
                            <h1 id="fittext1">1</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="queueholding">
                        <h1 id="fittext2">100</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="messages">
                    <div class="messagewrapper">
                        <div class="messagesubject">
                            <div class="subjecttext">
                                <h2 id="fittext3">Enter Subject here</h2>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="messageimportance">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id ="statuscolorwrap">
                <div id="queuecolors">
                    <div id="topcolor">

                    </div>
                    <div id="bottomcolor">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="announcementwrap">
                <div id="datetimewrapper">
                    <h3 id="fittext4">12/12/2014 18:00</h3>
                </div>
                <div id="anpicturewrap">
                    <img src="images/pic.jpg" alt=""/>
                </div>
                <div id="antextwrap">
                    <div id="text">
                        <h4 id="fittext5">sample text</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("h1").fitText(1);
            $("#fittext2").fitText(1.2);
            $("#fittext3").fitText(1.2);
            $("#fittext4").fitText(1.2, {minFontSize: '20px', maxFontSize: '30px'});
            $("#fittext5").fitText(1.2);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

https://github.com/davatron5000/FitText.js

Comment: It might help if you put together a JSFiddle that showed the problem. It is a little hard to visualize the issue.

Comment: I received a space on my queuestats div in JSFiddle that I am not gettnig with my testing in chrome. Here is the link to JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/neggly/57tVW/

Comment: See my answer below. I cleaned up some of your CSS, and added an updated fiddle with the text size thing working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default margins on headings and some of the margins you have set are causing some of the alignment issues. If you switched some of that to padding, and used `box-sizing:border-box;` on some of those divs, it would make things a bit easier to style:

```
div {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

In the JS fiddle example, it doesn't look the Javascript to resize the text is actually being called on anything. When I turn on JQuery in the fiddle and then actually call the text-resize stuff on your elements it does work to resize the elements.

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    jQuery("#fittext1").fitText(.2);
    jQuery("#fittext2").fitText(.3);
    jQuery("#fittext3").fitText(.6);
    jQuery("#fittext4").fitText(1, {minFontSize: '20px', maxFontSize: '30px'});
    jQuery("#fittext5").fitText(1.2);
});
```

Edit: I updated some of your CSS so it worked the way you might have expected it to. I moved normalize to the top of your CSS, since it should be the first thing added. You will probably want to add some space and things in some of the boxes, but since I added the border-box, you can just do this with padding on the percentage sized elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/57tVW/2/

Comment: Thanks for the improvement suggestions.  I am always looking for those.  But, in your JSFiddle example, you will notice that the 100% and 100 on the top left are really small.  Can you inform me on how to make them bigger?

Comment: Also, use grouping: the jQuery code can be better written as: `jQuery('div[id^="fittext"]').fitText()`, or `jQuery('#fittext1, #fittext2, #fittext3, #fittext4, #fittext5').fitText();`

Comment: fitText is making them small. Looking at how that works, it looks like the default font size is 1/10th of the width of the container. Play around with the values in the fitText() JS. jQuery("#fittext1").fitText(.2); works well for the 1 columns, jQuery("#fittext2").fitText(.3); works well for the 100% column, you just have to find what works for your application.

Comment: I updated my example with better values used on fitText. This sizes the stuff better for your content, at least in the fiddle

Comment: I am having the same issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26342411/how-to-display-an-image-next-to-some-texts Would you happen to know how to fix the ellipses issue? Thanks.